# Regarding Ruby on Rails best practices, Where should I put methods for calculating key indicators and analysis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are building a big Rails Application (Multi-tenant SaaS), and one of the most important sections of the platform is a "Reports" page, full of graphs and key indicators for the platform's users. This indicators summarize and give information regarding many models at the same time and I am unsure on where to put the methods that calculate these indicators.

Our first thought was to choose which model should be responsible for each method. Most times it is an easy decision, but some of them could be "assigned" to more than one model, it feels "random" anywhere we put them. Also, as a downside they are scattered all over the code, and aren't easy to find.

We could put these methods almost anywhere in the App (keep as model methods, use helpers, create a "reporting" class, lib, etc.), but we would like know what would be considered best practices regarding these methods.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: 'Best Practice' is going to be a matter primarily of opinion. That said, IMO you ought to put them all in services.

Comment: Yes, I know that in the end this is a matter of opinion. My purpose was to read opinions of more experienced developers (than me at least), thank you very much for yours!

Comment: FWIW, one of the reasons a question can be closed is because it is **primarily opinion-based**. According to powers-that-be: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*

Comment: Well, if we give response with arguments, it can help in making decision.

I would go with service because you mention you will process some data based on the models you have. Services are really useful for slimming down the logic you otherwise have in models and controllers. (https://medium.com/selleo/essential-rubyonrails-patterns-part-1-service-objects-1af9f9573ca1)

Other candidate for custom extensions is lib, but that is better to be used when it does not heavily depend on your models. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the Services recommendation. Reading about that design pattern, I stumbled upon Query Objects that could also be a good candidate for this purpose. I will gather information and post an answer comparing these two options, cause it seems both could be the right approach.